# How to delete file from external storage in android 5

Tags: android, delete-file, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I used

```
File f=new File(MyPath);
f.delete();
```

and I used permissions `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but it's not worked in Android 5.

Logcat message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: storage/external_SD/mm.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mahestan_programming.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

> WE CANNOT DELETE AND WRITE FILES FROM MICRO SD-CARD SINCE VERSION 4.4. It is read only now.

Comment: Can you post your logcat log?

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev logcat don't send anything log for me.

Comment: Look carefully at all logcat messages for your application. There may be orange warnings with additional error info.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev Post Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
storage/external_SD/mm.txt
```

That is not a valid path. You should use

```
/storage/external_SD/mm.txt
```

That is not external storage to begin with. It is removable storage.

From Android 4.4 on apps cannot write to a micro SD card anymore.

Google decided as such.

We have to live with it. Buts difficult.

Comment: What do you mean? I told you that you cannot delete files from micro SD card since version 4.4. So what is not solved?

Comment: I mean is /storage/... that not solved. If files is "Private Mode" in the app, can't delete them? To delete a file, what to do?

Comment: YOU CANNOT DELETE FILES FROM MICRO SD CARD ANYMORE.

Comment: It's ok! But i can't write files to SD-Card, it is my problem.

Comment: No. You also cannot write files to sd card anymory. You cannot change the card. It is read only now.

Comment: Oops, Thanks. What is the reason? Security?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your file path carefully, the path is something likes below:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Audio/audio_20160622_081844.3gp";
File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete();
}
```

Comment: Android 5 may switch the rules of cards naming, so the path can be different/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
  final String imgPath=_filePaths.get(_postion);
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(view, "Delete Image?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("DELETE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        File file = new File(imgPath);
                        file.delete();

                        Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(view, "Image Deleted!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        View sbView = snackbar1.getView();
                        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        snackbar1.show();

                    }
                });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        snackbar.show();
```

If it didn't works means post the  logcat and the codes your are using

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, which means that the file path `storage/external_SD/mm.txt` is wrong.

On my device I have different locations, and one of them is what you want, I guess.

1. `/external_sd/` - without `storage` prefix
2. `/storage/sdcard0` - virtual SD card, provided by Sony
3. `/storage/sdcard1` - real physical SD card, inserted into device

Also you can manually view your file system in Android Studio. Please click "Tools" -> "Android" -> "Android Device Monitor". Choose youe device at the lefy and tab "File explorer" at the right and you will able to view all files on your device.

Comment: My path is Ok. logcat send "Permission Denied" message in android 5.